# Image next to text box alignment

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, alignment

I'm sure this is relatively simple problem but after some fiddling I'm not finding much luck, will fix one thing then another problem arises. As you can see below *(this is on desktop, mobile works perfect)* the text boxes are way too big, leaving loads of white space below texts, some images are a good size, some are too big, the top one looks the best. The idea being the image spans across one side then the text box is the same height next to it.

[image]

Here is a picture of the mobile for reference

[image]

I wont link all the HTML and CSS, just the relevant stuff. Any advice is welcome and appreciated.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;600&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <meta name="description" content="Jordan Squres, mixed martial arts trainer, working out of Oxfordshire">
    <meta name="keywords" content="MMA, martial arts, personal trainer, self defence, exercise">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="autor" content="Descisive Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Jordan Squires, Home</title>
</head>
<body >
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href=" /"class="logo">Jordan Squires</a>
        <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
        <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="navitem"> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"> <a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"> <a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"> <a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<section class="home-hero">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="img-hero">
            <img src="images/portfolio1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info-hero">
            <h1>Jordan</h1>
            <h2>MMA Instructor</h2>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            <br>
            <br>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container" id="even">
        <div class="img-hero">
            <img src="images/portfolio2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info-hero">
            <h1>Shotokan Karate</h1>
            <h2>Black Belt</h2>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            <br>
            <br>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="img-hero">
            <img src="images/portfolio3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info-hero">
            <h1>Jeet Kune Do</h1>
            <h2>Black Belt</h2>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            <br>
            <br>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    <div class="flex-container"id="even">
        <div class="img-hero">
            <img src="images/portfolio4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info-hero">
            <h1>Brazilian Jiu Jitsu</h1>
            <h2>Purple Belt</h2>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            <br>
            <br>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="img-hero">
            <img src="images/portfolio5.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info-hero">
            <h1>Jordan</h1>
            <h2>MMA Instructor</h2>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            <br>
            <br>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: var(--white);
}

a{
    color: var(--main-txt);
    text-decoration: none;
}

:root{
    --white: #F1FAEE;
    --outline-color: #000000;
    --bg-color: #1D3557;
    --main-txt: #457B9D;
    --alt-txt: #A8DADC;
    --red: #E63946;

    --ff: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    --ff2: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

    --fw-l: 300;
    --fw-n: 400;
    --fw-m: 600;
    --fw-b: 700;

    --fs-1: ;
    --fs-2: ;
    --fs-3: ;
    --fs-p: ;

    --shadow: 0px 7px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

/*global style container*/

.container{
    max-width: 1360px;
}

/*Navbar styles*/

.navbar{
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-family: var(--ff2);
}

.navbar ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar ul a{
    display: block;
    padding: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: var(--fw-n)
}

.navbar ul a:hover{
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--white);
}

.navbar .logo{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-thickness: 0.2rem;
    text-underline-offset: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar .menu{
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.navbar .menu-icon{
    padding: 2.8rem 2rem;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .menu-icon .nav-icon{
    background: var(--bg-color);
    display: block;
    height: .2rem;
    width: 1.8rem;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
}

.navbar .menu-icon .nav-icon:before{
    background: var(--bg-color);
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    top: .5rem;
}

.navbar .menu-icon .nav-icon:after{
    background: var(--bg-color);
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    top: -.5rem;
}

.navbar .menu-btn{
    display: none;
}

.navbar .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu{
    max-height: 36rem;
}

.navbar .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon{
    background: transparent;
}

.navbar .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:before{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 0;
}

.navbar .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:after{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
}

/*Homepage main section*/
.home-hero{
 margin: 1rem auto;
}

.flex-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img-hero{
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: -3px;
}

.info-hero{
    width: 90%;
    font-family: var(--ff);
    border:  1px solid var(--outline-color);
    padding: 3rem;
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

/*Image styles*/
.img-hero img{
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    border: 1px solid var(--outline-color);
}
/*Info styles*/
.info-hero h1{
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: var(--white);
}

.info-hero h2{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
    color: var(--red);
}

.info-hero h1 h2{
    font-family: var(--ff2);
}

.info-hero p{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: justify;
    color: var(--alt-txt);

}
/*Media for Navbar*/

@media (min-width: 760px) {
    .navbar{
        height: 6.7rem;
    }

    .navbar li{
        float: left;
    }
    .navbar li a{
        padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
    }
    .navbar .menu{
        clear: none;
        float: right;
        max-height: none;
    }

    .navbar .menu-icon{
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar .logo{
        padding: 2rem;
    }

    .flex-container{
        flex-direction: row;
        margin: 2rem auto;
    }

    .img-hero{
        width: 50%;
        margin: inherit;
    }

    .info-hero{
        width: 45%;
        padding: 2rem;

    }

    #even{
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if all your css code was posted as the top part seems to have cut off an element for the margin: 1rem.
However, if I had to guess from just what was there it would be the padding: 3rem in the .info-hero class. Try removing that or lessening it and see if it helps.

Comment: I did not realise the text would show in a scroll frame, I have added all the HTML and CSS now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example I just wrote for you, you may adjust it according to your needs.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.img-hero, .info-hero {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.img-hero img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.info-hero {
  background: violet;
  color: white;
}

.info-hero > * {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="img-hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/900/700" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="info-hero">
    <h1>Jordan</h1>
    <h2>MMA Instructor</h2>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      <br>
      <br>
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="info-hero">
    <h1>Jordan</h1>
    <h2>MMA Instructor</h2>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      <br>
      <br>
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="img-hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, from what i can see you have reduced padding and shared the space by 50/50 % width? That leaves images either squashed or large spaces unfilled with text?